# Modular arithmetic - is this a "legal" substitution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that

$$a \equiv b ~(\text{mod}~3)$$ and $$c \cdot a \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~3)$$

Can I substitute $a$ with $b$? I mean:

$$c\cdot b \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~3)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

We have $b = a + 3k$, so $$c\cdot b = c\cdot(a + 3k) = c\cdot a + c\cdot 3k \equiv c\cdot a (\mod 3)$$

Comment: I think your answer would be vastly improved with the addition of the word "yes".

Comment: fair enough, added